# Color of header is not changing in react-native Stack Navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Here is the code snippet of stack navigator:

```
const MenuNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Menu: { screen: Menu },
    Dishdetail: { screen: Dishdetail },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Menu",
    navigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#512DA8",
      },
      headerTintColor: "#fff",
      headerTitleStyle: {
        color: "#fff",
      },
    },
  }
);
```

Everything is working fine but that code cant changes the color of my header.

*Here is the screenshot of my application :*

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

try this shape

```
const screens=createStackNavigator({
Menu ,
Dishdetail}
,{
  defaultNavigationOptions:{
    headerStyle:{
      height:90 ,
      backgroundColor:'#512DA8',
      borderBottomColor:'transparent'

          }, headerTitleStyle:{
      alignItems:'flex-end',
            color: "#fff",
      paddingLeft:theme.sizes.padding
    },}

});
```

till me if it work or not

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
const MenuNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Menu: {screen: Menu},
    Dishdetail: {screen: Dishdetail},
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Menu',
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#512DA8',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
      headerTitleStyle: {
        color: '#fff',
      },
    },
  },
);
```

`navigationOptions` is used for individual screens in version 4. Use `defaultNavigationOptions` if you want your properties to be applied to all screens in the navigator.

Documentation example: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/stack-navigator-1.0/#examples.